# What is a verb meaning "bringing out emotion within someone?"

Tags: word-choice

For example: when you are listening to a song and a piece of it moves you emotionally. What verb could be used to describe the "vivification" of that emotion?

Comment: How about "emotive"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could say that it **stirs** emotion(s).

( This is in the sense of awakening, not mixing up.)

Answer (score 1):

Something can evoke a certain emotion or response. "Evoke" is defined by dictionary.com, for instance, as "to call up or produce (memories, feelings, etc.)"

Answer (score 1):

***to flush out emotion***

means to bring to light emotion

> [**Quality Teaching in a Culture of Coaching**](https://books.google.ca/books?id=4Uu_AAAAQBAJ&pg=PA62&dq=%22flush%20out%20emotion%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=5ZUkVbqoLLjasATBkYHQBw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22flush%20out%20emotion%22&f=false) - Page 62 Stephen
>   G. Barkley - 2010
>
> ... yet a feeling remains just what the person feels. It's neither
>   right nor wrong, appropriate or inappropriate. It's just what's so. As
>   coaches, we can **flush out emotion** by gently and objectively
>   confirming what we heard (even if we "heard" it

where:

> **flush out**
>
> transitive verb
>
> :  to bring to light :  make public or available
>
> Merriam-Webster Unabridged Dictionary

Answer (score 1):

### **provocative**

[pruh-vok-uh-tiv] -[dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/provocative)

adjective:

> 1. tending or serving to provoke; inciting, stimulating, irritating, or vexing.

noun:

> 2. something provocative.

**provoke** [pruh-vohk] -[dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/provoke)

verb: (used with object), provoked, provoking.

> 2. to **stir up**, arouse, or call forth (feelings, desires, or activity): *The mishap provoked a hearty laugh.*
> 3. to incite or stimulate (a person, animal, etc.) to action.
> 4. to give rise to, induce, or bring about: *What could have provoked such an incident?*

Colloquially, *provocative* connotates a sexual reference (notice the lack of Collins' definition #1 for 'provocative': *acting as a stimulus or incitement, esp to anger or sexual desire*). IMO, this is only because they're some of our stronger and readily identifiable emotions. However its literal definition, from the Latin: *prōvocāre*, is ***to call forth***; I.e.,  *eliciting*.

**Whatever emotions the provocative subject matter provokes are the consumer's prerogative to elicit.**

---

**elicit** /ēˈlisət/ verb –[Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=elicit&oq=elicit&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l2j69i59l3.1455j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)

> evoke or draw out (a response, answer, or fact) from someone in reaction to one's own actions or questions.

Comment: "arousing" has a similar meaning, down to the possible sexual meaning.

Comment: Based on the question, I think "evoke" is better than "provoke", as it has more positive connotations.

Comment: @augurar - That's in [this answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/238081/what-is-a-verb-meaning-bringing-out-emotion-within-someone/238082#238082). I came back to add the definition of *elicit*; what I think the real winner here is.

Answer (score 0):

You could say that it **evokes** a certain emotion.

> *Evoke* (verb)
>
> : to bring (a memory, feeling, image, etc.) into the mind
>
> : to cause (a particular reaction or response) to happen
>
> ([Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/evoke))

Answer (score 0):

> [**touch**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/touch) verb, 15:
>    to affect with some feeling or emotion, especially tenderness, pity, gratitude, etc.:
>    *Their sufferings **touched** his heart.*
>    [*It touches me that you should say such a thing.*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22it%20touches%20me%20that%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl)
>    [*The poem really touched me.*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22poem%20really%20touched%20me%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl)

If OP wanted an *adjective*, I could suggest ***emotive*** (OED: Arousing or able to arouse strong feeling or emotion), but I don't think there's a *noun* derivative from that source with exactly the sense required (such that one could refer to the "touchingness" of a poem, say).

In principle, ***affectiveness*** ought to work for the abstract noun, but it seems a bit "affected" to me. The best I can come up with is...

> [**poignancy**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/poignancy) noun, 2:
>    a quality that arouses emotions (especially pity or sorrow)

...but as that definition indicates, it's particularly associated with one specific *type* of emotion.